# How to answer "What are you interested in professionally"?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, job-description

I am applying for a job from stackoverflow careers. It is a remote job and my experience matches the job description. There are 3 questions asked on the company's website two of them were expected and i have provided answers to them as below:

Q: What makes you interested in joining Company_Name?

A: I am an experienced Node.js Developer and have enthusiasm for developing Web applications and REST APIs. I enjoy working in a team environment, and I get along well with people. I am also a passionate open source contributor and would love to work with Company_Name.

Q: Where are you employed right now? Why are you looking to change your job? If you already left, why?

A: As a Web Developer at my current job I have had experience with creating many Backend Web APIs. I have also created applications that work with OAuth, AWS, and many libraries. I am enthusiastic about working with Company_Name to create better and scalable API solutions. I am changing my job to work remotely due to pandemic of Covid-19.

This is my first time applying for a job online so apologies if you see these answers unprofessional and i would appreciate if you could improve them.

Finally the third question was a little vague for me because i hadn't seen it before. What should i mention in this question's answer?

Q: What are you interested in professionally

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thank you for the advice.

Comment: NAA, but your first answer does not say anything about why you chose this particular company.

Comment: @AsheraH i used a previous cover letter for this one. I realized it too that the answer was not fit but couldn't come up with a better explanation than that at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

What technologies are you interested in keeping up to date with, what business practices, source control methodologies, what ideally do you see yourself doing in one/five years time?

Basically, what do you want to do with your career in a professional capacity over the next few years?

You're expected demonstrate enthusiasm in something that you want to work with.